# How to pass values of variables that I got from one method, To another method

Tags: java

So , Basically I started on this program where, If a user enters 1 , He can buy the stuff, if he enters 2 he can view his stuff, and if he presses 3, he can update it , Also if he enters 4 he can exit the looping.

So far I've done this much

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThumbDrives {

    public static void data()
    {
        System.out.print("HD of 512MB (@ 10$ per)");
        System.out.print("HD of 512MB (@ 10$ per)");
        System.out.print("HD of 512MB (@ 10$ per)");
        System.out.print("HD of 512MB (@ 10$ per)");
        int i1;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {   
        int i1,i2,i3,i4,R1,R2,R3,R4;
        int ch,choi=0;
        do {

        Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your Choice -;");
        System.out.println("1) Entering the data");
        System.out.println("2) Displaying the data");
        System.out.println("3) Updating the data");
        System.out.println("4) Press 4 to exit");
        ch = choice.nextInt();
            switch(ch)
            {
            case 1:

                break;
            case 2: 

                break;
            case 3:

                break;
            case 4:

                break;
            default: 
                System.out.print("Your choice isnt appropriate");

            }

        }
        while(choi!=4);

    }
}
```

But, I want it so that if i get the values entered in the method data, They can be accessed anywhere in the class.

Sorry I am new to java any helps will be much appreciated :)

Comment: declare your variable outside methods

Comment: I am not able to understand last part of your question.

Comment: I don't see where you enter data in the method data. Do you want to input i1?

Comment: Have you used that word `sh*t`. I'm not sure this is allowed on StackOverFlow

Comment: So you want int i1,i2,i3,i4,R1,R2,R3,R4;
        int ch,choi=0;

to be accessed anywhere in the class right?

Comment: sorry for being a bit of a prude, but I don't think vulgar language is necessary here...

Comment: if you want it accessible anywhere in that class, make it a class variable (declare it private outside the method)

Comment: I think you best start with a tutorial Object Oriented java programming.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variable scope question.

A local variable is declared within the scope of a method. So, if you write

```
int i1;
```

in the scope of the data() method, you can access it only in data.

If you move it from a local variable to a class field, then it will be accessible in the entire class. So, move that i1 declaration outside of data(), keeping it within

```
public class ThumbDrives {
    ...
}
```

if it is declared "static" it is referred to as a class variable.

```
public class ThumbDrives {
     static int i1;
}
```

a class/static variable is available to all instances of the class.

if it is not declared static

```
public class ThumbDrives {
     int i1;
}
```

then it will be available in just that instance in memory.

Answer (score 0):

**Declare your Required variables globally so that you can access your required values any where throughout the class**

initialise these variables outside of your method

```
 int i1,i2,i3,i4,R1,R2,R3,R4;

    int ch,choi=0;
```